Solving the wave equation of a tensor $h_{\mu\nu} = (1/2) (e_\mu e_\nu + e_\nu e_\mu)$
It is known that the solution to the wave equation for a tensor
$$
\square h_{\mu\nu} = 0
$$
is
$$
h_{\mu\nu}(\vec{x}, t) = \int \frac{d^3k}{(2\pi)^3} \sum_{\lambda=+,\times} \left( \epsilon_{\mu\nu}^{(\lambda)}(\vec{k})  a_{\vec{k},\lambda} e^{i(\vec{k}\cdot\vec{x} - \omega_k t)} + \epsilon_{\mu\nu}^{(\lambda)*}(\vec{k})  a_{\vec{k},\lambda}^* e^{-i(\vec{k}\cdot\vec{x} - \omega_k t)} \right)
$$
It is also know that in geometric algebra, this equation holds:
$$
h_{\mu\nu} = (1/2) (e_\mu e_\nu + e_\nu e_\mu)
$$
I am interested in the wave equation, where I have replaced $h_{\mu\nu}$ with its geometric algebra formulation $(1/2) (e_\mu e_\nu + e_\nu e_\mu)$.
$$
\frac{1}{2} \square (e_\mu e_\nu + e_\nu e_\mu) = 0
$$
Specifically, I am looking for an expression of $e_\mu$ and of $e_\nu$ in terms of a sum over modes (instead of with the usual $h_{\mu\nu}$), that satisfies the wave equation above.

Can you provide some definitions or a reference for where this comes from? Are $\omega_k$ and $a_{\vec{k},\lambda}$ continuous functions of $\vec{k}$, are $e_\mu$ and $e_\nu$ standard tensors, are $\epsilon_{\mu,\nu}^{(\lambda)}(\vec{k})$ Levi-Civita tensors and over what geometry and basis, etc.?

@QPhysl $e_{\mu\nu}(k)$ are the polarization tensors. The $a$ are the coefficients of the fourier series. Each element of the sum corresponds to a mode of excitation of the wave. For example https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.07338 equation (7) is similar. I use the linearized Einstein Hilbert equation in the Donder gauge, then apply the transverse-traceless gauge on the equation of motion, yielding the wave equation $\square h_{\mu\nu}=0$.

Crossposted from https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4930159/11127

@QPhysl an alternative notation I have seen is as follows:
$$
h_{\mu\nu}(\vec{x}, t) = {\rm Re} \int {\rm d}^3k \left( A_+ (\vec{k}) e_{\mu\nu}^+ (\vec{k}) +A_\times (\vec{k} )e_{\mu\nu}^\times (\vec{k})  \right) e^{-i(\vec{k}\cdot\vec{x} - \omega_k t)}
$$

There are symmetric 2-forms $h_{\mu \nu}$ that cannot be represented as a symmetrized direct product of a 1-form $e_\mu$ with itself. So I do not understand what is exactly the content of the statement $h_{\mu\nu} = (e_\mu e_\nu + e_\nu e_\mu)/2$, this is not always true. Or am I misinterpreting your statements?

@void $h_{\mu\nu}$ is a metric tensor.

@Anon21 Sure, but does your object $e_\mu$ have more indices or further structure or is it just a simple 1-form? Because if it is a 1-form, your statement about the decomposition is incorrect/non-generic.

@void here e_mu is a basis vector of GA(3,1).

@Anon21 Oh, I see, so you are essentially decomposing your metric into a $\gamma$-matrix basis $(\gamma_\mu)^A{}_B$ and there is an implicit matrix product (and a quotienting of the natural metric $\delta^A{}_B$ from the result). Interesting.

Because $h_{\mu \nu} = (1 / 2)\left(e_{\mu} e_{\nu}+e_{\nu} e_{\mu}\right)$ this implies that it is a totally symmetric tensor, i.e., $h_{\mu \nu} = h_{\nu \mu}$.
This suggests that the polarization tensor $\epsilon_{\mu \nu}^{(\lambda)}$ should also be totally symmetric. Let us write
$$\epsilon_{\mu \nu}^{(\lambda)} = (1 / 2)\left(\alpha_{\mu}^\lambda \alpha_{\nu}^\lambda + \alpha_{\nu}^\lambda \alpha_{\mu}^\lambda \right)$$
Thus, substituting the above in
$$ h_{\mu \nu}(\vec{x}, t)=\int \frac{d^{3} k}{(2 \pi)^{3}} \sum_{\lambda=+, x}\left(\epsilon_{\mu \nu}^{(\lambda)}(\vec{k}) a_{\vec{k}, \lambda} e^{i\left(\vec{k} \cdot \vec{x}-\omega_{k} t\right)}+\epsilon_{\mu \nu}^{(\lambda) *}(\vec{k}) a_{k, \lambda}^{*} e^{-i\left(\vec{k} \cdot \vec{x}-\omega_{k} t\right)}\right) $$
we find
$$ e_{\mu} e_{\nu}+e_{\nu} e_{\mu} = \int \frac{d^{3} k}{(2 \pi)^{3}} \sum_{\lambda=+, x}\left([\alpha_{\mu}^\lambda \alpha_{\nu}^\lambda + \alpha_{\nu}^\lambda \alpha_{\mu}^\lambda ] a_{\vec{k}, \lambda} e^{i\left(\vec{k} \cdot \vec{x}-\omega_{k} t\right)}+[\alpha_{\mu}^\lambda \alpha_{\nu}^\lambda + \alpha_{\nu}^\lambda \alpha_{\mu}^\lambda ]^* a_{k, \lambda}^{*} e^{-i\left(\vec{k} \cdot \vec{x}-\omega_{k} t\right)}\right) \,. $$
We can see from the above that
$$ e_{\mu} e_{\nu} = \int \frac{d^{3} k}{(2 \pi)^{3}} \sum_{\lambda=+, x}\left( \alpha_{\mu}^\lambda \alpha_{\nu}^\lambda a_{\vec{k}, \lambda} e^{i\left(\vec{k} \cdot \vec{x}-\omega_{k} t\right)}+[\alpha_{\mu}^\lambda \alpha_{\nu}^\lambda ]^* a_{k, \lambda}^{*} e^{-i\left(\vec{k} \cdot \vec{x}-\omega_{k} t\right)}\right) \,. $$
and thus
$$ e_{\mu} = \int \frac{d^{3} k}{(2 \pi)^{3}} \sum_{\lambda=+, x}\left( \alpha_{\mu}^\lambda \sqrt{a_{\vec{k}, \lambda}} e^{\frac{i}{2}\left(\vec{k} \cdot \vec{x}-\omega_{k} t\right)} + \alpha_{\mu}^{\lambda*} \sqrt{a_{k, \lambda}^{*}} e^{-\frac{i}{2}\left(\vec{k} \cdot \vec{x}-\omega_{k} t\right)}\right) \,. $$
Note the square root on the term $a_{k, \lambda}$ and the 1/2 fraction on the exponentials.

Restatement of the Question to Make it Easier to View While Writing the Solution

It is known that the solution to the wave equation for a tensor
$$ \square h_{\mu\nu} = 0 $$
is
$$ h_{\mu\nu}(\vec{x}, t) = \int \frac{d^3k}{(2\pi)^3}
 \sum_{\lambda=+,\times} \left( \epsilon_{\mu\nu}^{(\lambda)}(\vec{k}) 
 a_{\vec{k},\lambda} e^{i(\vec{k}\cdot\vec{x} - \omega_k t)} +
 \epsilon_{\mu\nu}^{(\lambda)*}(\vec{k})  a_{\vec{k},\lambda}^*
 e^{-i(\vec{k}\cdot\vec{x} - \omega_k t)} \right) $$
It is also know that in geometric algebra, this equation holds:
$$ h_{\mu\nu} = (1/2) (e_\mu e_\nu + e_\nu e_\mu) $$
I am interested in the wave equation, where I have replaced
$h_{\mu\nu}$ with its geometric algebra formulation $(1/2) (e_\mu
e_\nu + e_\nu e_\mu)$.
$$ \frac{1}{2} \square (e_\mu e_\nu + e_\nu e_\mu) = 0 $$
Specifically, I am looking for an expression of $e_\mu$ and of $e_\nu$
in terms of a sum over modes (instead of with the usual $h_{\mu\nu}$),
that satisfies the wave equation above.

Solution Steps
Start from Maxwell's Equations:
$$
\vec\nabla \times \vec E = -\frac{d}{d\,t}\vec B \,\text{  ,  } \,
\vec\nabla \times \vec H = \vec J + \frac{d}{d\,t}\vec D \\
\vec\nabla \bullet \vec D = \rho \,\text{  ,  } \,
\vec\nabla \bullet \vec B = 0 \\
\vec B = \mu \vec H \,\text{  ,  } \,
\vec D = \epsilon E 
$$
Since $\vec\nabla \bullet \vec B = 0$, then $\vec B$ is Divergent-less and can be represented as a curl of a Vector potential $\vec A$ as follows:
$$\vec B=\vec \nabla \times \vec A$$
From  $\vec B = \mu \vec H $ where $\mu$ is usually constant in free-space, and $\vec\nabla \times \vec H = \vec J + \frac{d}{d\,t}\vec D$ where $\vec J=0$ in free-space, then
$$
\vec\nabla \times \vec B =\frac{d}{d\,t}\mu \vec D=\frac{d}{d\,t}\mu \epsilon \vec E \\
\vec\nabla \times \left(\vec \nabla \times \vec A \right) =
\frac{d}{d\,t}\mu \vec D=\frac{d}{d\,t}\mu \epsilon \vec E$$
$$\left(\vec\nabla \times
\left(\vec\nabla \times \vec B \right)\right) = \vec\nabla \times \left(\vec\nabla \times 
\left( \vec \nabla \times \vec A \right)\right) = \frac{d}{d\,t}\mu \vec \nabla \times \vec D=\frac{d}{d\,t}\mu
\left( \nabla \times \epsilon \right) \vec E 
+ \frac{d}{d\,t} \mu \epsilon \vec \nabla \times \vec E 
$$
Since in the question statement, all of the solutions are sums and integrals of plane waves of the forms $e^{-i(\vec{k}\cdot\vec{x} - \omega_k t)}$ and $ e^{i(\vec{k}\cdot\vec{x} - \omega_k t)}$ then:
$$\left( \nabla \times \epsilon \right) \vec E=0 \,\text{,  and  }\,
\\ \vec \nabla \times \vec E = -\frac{d}{d \, t} \vec B
= -\frac{d}{d \, t} \vec \nabla \times \vec A
$$
so that
$$
\vec\nabla \times
\left(\vec\nabla \times 
\left( \vec \nabla \times \vec A \right)\right) = 
\frac{d}{d\,t} \mu \epsilon \left( \vec \nabla \times \vec E \right) 
=\frac{d}{d\,t} \mu \epsilon \left(-\frac1{d\,t}\vec B  \right)
=-\frac{d^2}{d\,t^2} \mu \epsilon \left(\vec \nabla \times \vec A  \right)
$$
Thus from the vector identity (substituting $\nabla $ for both $A$ and $B$ in that reference) for
$\vec \nabla \times \left( \vec \nabla \times 
\left(\vec \nabla \times \vec A\right)\right)$:
$$
\left(-\nabla^2 + \vec \nabla \vec \nabla \bullet  \right)
\left(\vec \nabla \times \vec A \right)
+\frac{d^2}{d\,t^2} \mu \epsilon \left(\vec \nabla \times \vec A  \right)=0
$$
But since $\vec \nabla \times \vec A$ is divergent-less, then
$\vec \nabla \vec \nabla \bullet \vec\nabla\times \vec A=\vec 0$ and:
$$\left(\mu \epsilon \frac{d^2}{d\,t^2} - \nabla^2  \right)
\left(\vec \nabla \times \vec A \right)= 
\square \left(\vec \nabla \times \vec A \right)
=\vec 0\ \\
\text{  with the speed of light }\,c=\frac1{\sqrt{\mu\epsilon}}$$
Note, the speed of light is determined by the relationships between $\vec k$ in the question and $\omega t$ for the plane waves in the Green's function. Obviously in media with index of refraction $\epsilon \ne \epsilon_0$ the speed of light might not be the same as that in an non-warped vacuum.  Also "the said signature is the Minkowski metric convention (+ − − −)" according to this quoted reference on the Alembert operator:

In Minkowski space, in standard coordinates (t, x, y, z), it has the form $$ $$

$$ $$ Here  $$
\Delta\overset{\triangle}  ={\displaystyle \nabla ^{2}}$$
is the 3-dimensional Laplacian and $η_{μ\,ν}$ is the inverse Minkowski metric with

Note that the μ and ν summation indices range from 0 to 3: see Einstein notation.

$$
\square \overset{\Delta}{=}
\left(\mu \epsilon\frac{d^2}{d\,t^2} - \nabla^2 \right)
=\left(\frac1{c^2}\frac{d^2}{d\,t^2} - \nabla^2 \right)
\\ \text{where $c$ is the local speed of light in the vacuum}
$$
From the article "Electromagnetic Four Potential" is quoted:

In special relativity, the electric and magnetic fields transform
under Lorentz transformations. This can be written in the form of a
rank two tensor - the electromagnetic tensor. The 16 contravariant
components of the electromagnetic tensor, using Minkowski metric
convention (+ − − −), are written in terms of the electromagnetic
four-potential and the four-gradient as:
$${\displaystyle F^{\mu \nu }=\partial ^{\mu }A^{\nu }-\partial ^{\nu }A^{\mu }={\begin{bmatrix}0&-E_{x}/c&-E_{y}/c&-E_{z}/c\\E_{x}/c&0&-B_{z}&B_{y}\\E_{y}/c&B_{z}&0&-B_{x}\\E_{z}/c&-B_{y}&B_{x}&0\end{bmatrix}}}$$
If the said signature is instead (- + + -+) then:
$$
{\displaystyle F'\,^{\mu \nu }=\partial '\,^{\mu }A^{\nu }-\partial '\,^{\nu }A^{\mu }={\begin{bmatrix}0&E_{x}/c&E_{y}/c&E_{z}/c\\-E_{x}/c&0&B_{z}&-B_{y}\\-E_{y}/c&-B_{z}&0&B_{x}\\-E_{z}/c&B_{y}&-B_{x}&0\end{bmatrix}}}
$$

The equation from the question is basically a Green's Function integral and sum:

$$ h_{\mu\nu}(\vec{x}, t) = \int \frac{d^3k}{(2\pi)^3}
 \sum_{\lambda=+,\times} \left( \epsilon_{\mu\nu}^{(\lambda)}(\vec{k}) 
 a_{\vec{k},\lambda} e^{i(\vec{k}\cdot\vec{x} - \omega_k t)} +
 \epsilon_{\mu\nu}^{(\lambda)*}(\vec{k})  a_{\vec{k},\lambda}^*
 e^{-i(\vec{k}\cdot\vec{x} - \omega_k t)} \right) $$

Because:
$$\left(\epsilon_{\mu\nu}^{(\lambda)}(\vec{k}) 
 a_{\vec{k},\lambda} e^{i(\vec{k}\cdot\vec{x}+\omega_k t)}\right)^*
=
\epsilon_{\mu\nu}^{(\lambda)*}(\vec{k})  a_{\vec{k},\lambda}^*
 e^{-i(\vec{k}\cdot\vec{x}-\omega_k t)}$$
then this reduces to the real part
$$
\left( \epsilon_{\mu\nu}^{(\lambda)}(\vec{k}) 
 a_{\vec{k},\lambda} e^{i(\vec{k}\cdot\vec{x} - \omega_k t)} +
 \epsilon_{\mu\nu}^{(\lambda)*}(\vec{k})  a_{\vec{k},\lambda}^*
 e^{-i(\vec{k}\cdot\vec{x} - \omega_k t)} \right)$$
$$=2\,\textit{Real}\,
\left(
  \left( \epsilon_{\mu\nu}^{(\lambda)}(\vec{k}) 
   a_{\vec{k},\lambda} e^{i(\vec{k}\cdot\vec{x} - \omega_k t)} 
   \right)
\right)$$
$$
=\textit{Real}\,
\left(
     \left(a+\sqrt{-1}b\right)+
     \left(a- \sqrt{-1}b\right)
\right)=2\,a$$
$$=2*\textit{Real}\,
\left( 
     \epsilon_{\mu\nu}^{(\lambda)}(\vec{k}) 
     a_{\vec{k},\lambda} e^{i(\vec{k}\cdot\vec{x} - \omega_k t)}
\right)
$$ This accounts for the factor of $\frac1{2}$ in $ h_{\mu\nu} = \frac1{2} (e_\mu e_\nu + e_\nu e_\mu) $, since $\textit{Real}\,\left(e_\mu e_\nu\right)= \frac1{2} \left(e_\mu e_\nu + \left(e_\mu e_\nu\right)^*\right)$.
Now consider again the question:

$$\square h_{\mu\nu} = 0$$

When evaluating $\square h_{\mu\mu}=\square \vec A_{\mu\mu}$ the diagonal terms are all zero:
$$\square \vec A_{\mu\mu}=0 $$
So $\square h_{\mu\nu} = 0$ definitely holds in the case that $\mu=\nu$.
As for the off-diagonal elements in the tensor:

$${\displaystyle F^{\mu \nu }=\partial ^{\mu }A^{\nu }-\partial ^{\nu }A^{\mu }={\begin{bmatrix}0&-E_{x}/c&-E_{y}/c&-E_{z}/c\\E_{x}/c&0&-B_{z}&B_{y}\\E_{y}/c&B_{z}&0&-B_{x}\\E_{z}/c&-B_{y}&B_{x}&0\end{bmatrix}}}$$

By inspection of this tensor,
$$
{\displaystyle F^{\mu \nu }=\partial ^{\mu }A^{\nu }-\partial ^{\nu }A^{\mu }}
$$
So
$$
\left({\displaystyle F^{\mu \nu }=\partial ^{\mu }A^{\nu }-\partial ^{\nu }A^{\mu }}\right)
+
\left({\displaystyle F^{\nu \mu }=\partial ^{\nu }A^{\mu }-\partial ^{\mu }A^{\nu }}\right)=0\, \text{  And }\,\square \left( \vec \nabla \times \vec A \right) = \vec 0
$$
Since (from the question):

$$\frac{1}{2} \square (e_\mu e_\nu + e_\nu e_\mu) = 0 $$

It seems that the tensors $e_\mu e_\nu$ and $e_\nu e_\mu$ must transform with the factor of $-1$ with the index shifts $\mu \to \nu$ and $\nu \to \mu$ just like
$$F^{\mu \, \nu}=-F^{'\, \mu \, \nu }=-F^{\nu \, \mu}$$ $$ $$that is that the sum is anti-symmetric under index swap.
This result was also as derived from Maxwell's equations, which generate the waves for the Green's functions that sums them up as plane waves times associated constants in a kernel integral, a sum over continuous modes, which as taken as such is really a kernel integral over continuous modes of vector plane waves (vectors "a quantity that has both size and direction", since they have wave momentum $\vec k$ directions and $_{⃗ ,}$ constant-multiplier magnitudes).
The approach is taken from the Electromagnetic side since previously quoted:

In special relativity, the electric and magnetic fields transform
under Lorentz transformations. This can be written in the form of a
rank two tensor - the electromagnetic tensor.

So the Electromagnetic field must also Lorenz transform in Malinowski space according to relativity too.  Gravitational fields also transform in the same way as fields with electromagnetic energy, because of the equivalence of confined electromagnetic energy and associated mass that accounts for confined energy there.
An Interesting Example from Geometric Algebra
The article "Geometric algebra" is quoted:

In ${\displaystyle {\mathcal {G}}(3,0)}$, a further familiar case occurs. Given a standard basis consisting of ortho-normal vectors
${\displaystyle e_{i}}$ of ${\displaystyle V}$, the set of all
${\displaystyle 2}$-vectors is spanned by
$${\displaystyle \{e_{3}e_{2},e_{1}e_{3},e_{2}e_{1}\}.}$$
Labelling these
$
{\displaystyle i}, 
{\displaystyle j} $ and $ 
{\displaystyle k} $(momentarily deviating from our uppercase convention), the subspace generated by
${\displaystyle 0}-$vectors and ${\displaystyle 2}-$vectors is exactly
${\displaystyle \{\alpha _{0}+i\alpha _{1}+j\alpha _{2}+k\alpha _{3}\mid \alpha _{i}\in \mathbb {R} \}}$. This set is seen to be the even subalgebra of
${\displaystyle {\mathcal {G}}(3,0)}$, and furthermore is isomorphic as an
${\displaystyle \mathbb {R} }$-algebra to the quaternions, another important algebraic system.

Now consider the quantity:
$$
\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial\,c\,t} 
- \hat i \frac{\partial}{\partial x}  
- \hat j \frac{\partial}{\partial y}  
- \hat l \frac{\partial}{\partial z}  
\right)
$$
With $a_0=\frac{\partial}{\partial c t}$,
$a_1=-\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$,
$a_2=-\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$,
$a_3=-\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$,
then there is now a representation for the wave-function operator $
\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial\,c\,t} 
- \hat i \frac{\partial}{\partial x}  
- \hat j \frac{\partial}{\partial y}  
- \hat l \frac{\partial}{\partial z}  
\right)
$ using Geometric Algebra.  This operator can operate on scalars or vectors (or even individual vector components that are scalars).
Geometric Algebra and Pauli Vectors
Another interesting quote from the article
"Geometric algebra" is quoted:

Every associative algebra has a matrix representation; replacing the three Cartesian basis vectors by the Pauli matrices gives a representation of ${\displaystyle {\mathcal {G}}(3,0)}:$
$${\displaystyle {\begin{aligned}e_{1}=\sigma _{1}=\sigma _{x}&={\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}}\\e_{2}=\sigma _{2}=\sigma _{y}&={\begin{pmatrix}0&-i\\i&0\end{pmatrix}}\\e_{3}=\sigma _{3}=\sigma _{z}&={\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}}\,.\end{aligned}}}$$
From the article "Pauli Matrices" is quoted:
The Pauli matrices obey the following commutation relations:
$${\displaystyle [\sigma _{j},\sigma _{k}]=2i\varepsilon _{jkl}\,\sigma _{l},}$$
where the structure constant $ε_{j k l}$ is the Levi-Civita symbol, and Einstein summation notation is used.
From this question:
$$ h_{\mu\nu} = (1/2) (e_\mu e_\nu + e_\nu e_\mu) $$

But this equation is the same as:



as $$ h_{\mu\nu} = (1/2) (e_\mu e_\nu + e_\nu e_\mu)
= \frac1{2} \left[e_{\mu}, e_{\nu} \right]$$
$$h_{\mu\nu}= (1/2) (e_\mu e_\nu + e_\nu e_\mu) 
=\frac1{2}\left[e_{\mu}, e_{\nu}\right]=\epsilon_{\mu \nu k}e_k$$
with $$ $$


$$ $$ as quoted from the Levi-Civita symbol article.

This can be compared to $\vec \nabla \times \vec A$ as:
$$\vec \nabla \times \vec A
=
{\begin{bmatrix}
\hat i & \hat j & \hat k \\
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial}{\partial z} \\
A_x & A_y & A_z \\ 
\end{bmatrix}}$$
With
$$\hat{i}\times \hat{j}=\hat{k} \, \text{  ,  } \, \hat{j}\times \hat{k}=\hat{l}  \, \text{  ,  } \,  
\hat{k}\times \hat{i}=\hat{j}$$
$$\hat{i}\times \hat{i}=\vec{0}  \, \text{  ,  } \,   \hat{j}\times \hat{j}=\vec{0}  \, \text{  ,  } \, 
\hat{k}\times \hat{k}=\vec{0}$$
$$\hat{i}\times \hat{j}=-\hat{j}\times\hat{i} \, \text{  ,  } \, 
\hat{j}\times \hat{k}=-\hat{k}\times\hat{j} \, \text{  ,  } \,
\hat{k}\times \hat{i}=-\hat{i}\times\hat{k} \, \text{  ,  } \,
$$
another way of writing these is using triads and dot products.  Starting with:
$$
\vec\nabla \times \vec A=
\left(
\frac1{d\,x}\hat{i}+
\frac1{d\,y}\hat{j}+
\frac1{d\,z}\hat{k}\right)\times
\left(
A_x\,\hat{i}+A_y\,\hat{j}+A_z\,\hat{k}
\right)
$$
$$
=\frac1{d\,x}\left(\hat{i}\times\hat{j}A_y+\hat{i}\times\hat{k}A_z\right)
+\frac1{d\,y}\left(\hat{j}\times\hat{i}A_x+\hat{j}\times\hat{k}A_z\right)
+\frac1{d\,z}\left(\hat{k}\times\hat{i}A_x+\hat{k}\times\hat{j}A_y\right)
$$
Then, proceeding with the new notation,
$$\vec \nabla \times \vec A =\\
\frac1{d\,x}\hat{i}\bullet\
   \left(\hat{i}\hat{k}\hat{j}-\hat{i}\hat{j}\hat{k}\right)
   \bullet \left(A_y\hat{j}+A_z\hat{k}\right)
\\+
\frac1{d\,y}\hat{j}\bullet\
   \left(\hat{j}(-\hat{k})\hat{i}+\hat{j}\hat{i}\hat{k}\right)
   \bullet \left(A_x\hat{i}+A_z\hat{k}\right)
\\+
\frac1{d\,z}\hat{k}\bullet\
   \left(\hat{k}\hat{j}\hat{i}-\hat{k}\hat{i}\hat{j}\right)
   \bullet \left(A_x\hat{i}+A_y\hat{j}\right)
$$
With $\vec\nabla=\left(\frac1{d\,x}\hat{i}+\frac1{d\,y}\hat{k}+\frac1{d\,k}\hat{k}\right)$ and $\vec{A}=\left(A_x\hat{i}+A_y\hat{j}+A_z\hat{k}\right)$, then in the new notation:
$$
\vec{\nabla}\times\vec{A}=\\
=\left(\frac1{d\,x}\hat{i}+\frac1{d\,y}\hat{k}+\frac1{d\,k}\hat{k}\right)
\times \left(A_x\hat{i}+A_y\hat{j}+A_z\hat{k}\right) =\\
=\vec{\nabla}\bullet\left(
\hat{i}\hat{k}\hat{j}-\hat{i}\hat{j}\hat{k}
+\hat{j}(-\hat{k})\hat{i}+\hat{j}\hat{i}\hat{k}
+\hat{k}\hat{j}\hat{i}-\hat{k}\hat{i}\hat{j}\right)
   \bullet \vec A
$$
For example, with $\hat{i}\hat{k}\hat{j}$, then with $\hat{i}$ on the left then $\nabla_i$ is selected on the left being $\frac1{d\,x}\hat{i}$.  And on the right $\hat{j}$ selects the $A_j$ element.  The direction of these two elements is then replaced by this operator as $\hat{k}$. And and these operators form a similar function to the "Levi-Civita_symbol" for the vector cross product as in Geometric Algebra.  Clearly, $\vec\nabla A$ is both perpendicular to the direction of travel of the plane wave (which is parallel to $\vec \nabla$ in Cartesion coordinates), an also parallel to $\vec A$ since there are no elements $?\hat{i}\hat{i}$ or
$\hat{i}\hat{i}?$ in example (using ? to represent any of $\hat{i}$,$\hat{j}$, or $\hat{k}$). For $\vec\nabla\times\vec A$, the direction is perpendicular to both the plane wave propagation and to $\vec A$ itself.

Why are you invoking vector calculus on a question that explicitly asks for geometric algebra interpretation? And why all this E&M stuff on a question about gravitational waves?

@Kyle Kanos :  the integral of wave functions includes the dot product of vectors because of the different directions of the plane waves.  As to the equivalence of the two, the bare electon mass, the rest mass, and the energy stored in the electromagnetic field, that is something that I am still learning about.  So aside from the bonus potential, that topic also makes this question very interesting to me to understand and answer.  The references seem to suggest an equivalence also for the transforms for Electrodynamics and relativity.

Your comment doesn't address either of the two points I raised.

@KyleKanos: I found an interesting quote Electromagnetism according to geometric algebra:"VA deals only with scalars and vectors and hence
does not contain geometric description beyond points
and lines. It should be noted that, the cross product,
triple product etc. of vectors and hence VA itself can
be defined only in 3D."
